# My domain is not visible to world

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, bind, wide-area-network

How I can make my myself hosted domain visible to world?

**Question Details:**

I have a domain `donotrape.me` which is not visible to world.
My System is **Debian 7 64BIT, Bind9, Apache**.

Debian firewall is on default mode (off, i think so (ref:https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFirewall)), Port 80 is open and forwarded to `192.168.1.2`

**named.conf** is as under:

```
        zone "donotrape.me" {
            type master;
            file "/etc/bind/zones/e.donotrape.me";
    };
```

**zone file** file is as under:

```
;; file: /etc/bind/zones/e.donotrape.me
;; domain: donotrape.me
$TTL 86400
donotrape.me   IN  SOA     NS1.IMSINGH.COM. ROOT.IMSINGH.COM. (
20130703021  ;Serial
3600        ;Refresh
1800        ;Retry
604800      ;Expire
86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
donotrape.me    IN  NS  NS1.IMSINGH.COM.
donotrape.me    IN  NS  NS2.IMSINGH.COM.
donotrape.me    IN  A   59.177.154.251
NS1 IN  A   59.177.154.251
NS2 IN  A   59.177.154.251
www IN  CNAME   NS1
```

This domain is registered with GoDaddy.com so nameserver there are:
`ns1.imsingh.com` & `ns2.imsingh.com`

The domain check reports you can see at http://www.intodns.com/donotrape.me
Mainly it shows these errors

`Nameservers A records  ERROR: Some of your DNS servers do not have A records at all. I could not find any A records for the following DNS servers:`
`ns2.imsingh.com`
`ns1.imsingh.com`
`You must have A records for all of your nameservers.`

`Mismatched NS records  WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.`
`Error  DNS servers responded   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:`
`The ones that did not respond are:`
`ns2.imsingh.com ns1.imsingh.com`

in lan it is runs well

*Can you suggest any solution so that this website is open to world*

## I finally purged iptables

`apt-get purge iptables`

## BUT STILL NO SOLUTION

### SO I  THINK FIREWALL IS NOT AN ISSUE OR THERE IS NO PROBLEM WITH MY SYSTEM

Comment: Try replacing the first `donotrape.me` (on the `SOA` line) with `@`.

Comment: port 53 (UDP and TCP) must be opened and forwarded for DNS.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu I think port is open as my ip 59.177.154.251 opens the website

Comment: 59.177.154.251 is declared as nameserver for your zone. So it will be queried about www.donotrapeme.com. And this query will be on port 53 UDP (and possibly port 53 TCP) but these ports are not opened. So nobody can't find the IP address of your site.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu

lsof -i :53 returns 

`COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`
`named   2241 bind   20u  IPv6   6085      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)`
`named   2241 bind   21u  IPv4   6089      0t0  TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)`
`named   2241 bind   22u  IPv4   6091      0t0  TCP global.imsingh.com:domain (LISTEN)`
`named   2241 bind   26u  IPv4  10889      0t0  TCP IMSINGH.COM:domain (LISTEN)`

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu

and this too
`named   2241 bind  512u  IPv6   6084      0t0  UDP *:domain`
`named   2241 bind  513u  IPv4   6088      0t0  UDP localhost:domain` 
`named   2241 bind  514u  IPv4   6090      0t0  UDP global.imsingh.com:domain`
`named   2241 bind  515u  IPv4  10888      0t0  UDP IMSINGH.COM:domain`

Comment: Yes, bind listen on these ports. But they are blocked from firewall. So the outside world cannot query your bind server. Is bind running on the firewall or on another server?

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu, so please tell me what to do, thanking you in advance

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu, 
# netstat -tulpn | grep :53
`tcp        0      0 59.177.154.251:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/named`      
`tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      `2241/named`      
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/named`      
`tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      2241/named`

Comment: `udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53186           0.0.0.0:*                           2489/avahi-daemon:` 
`udp        0      0 59.177.154.251:53       0.0.0.0:*                           2241/named`      
`udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:53          0.0.0.0:*                           2241/named`      
`udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           2241/named`      
`udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           2489/avahi-daemon:`

Comment: `udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                2241/named`      
`udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                2489/avahi-daemon:`

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu **IF IT IS POSSIBLE TO OPEN THE REQUIRED PORTS**

Comment: Can you resolve domain locally ?

Comment: @K.KPatel, YES, and even my ip works

Comment: It is not clear to me if you have 2 servers or just one. If you have one firewall and one server which runs web server and DNS server than my firewall rules should be ok. If this is the case and you stop firewall nothing will work because traffic will not be forwarded to 192.168.1.2 server. If you have only on server which is the firewall and also run web and dns server than forwarding should not be done and accept rules should be inserted on INPUT chain.

Comment: @LaurentiuRoescu, i have just one server. And i have **purged the iptables** `apt-get purge iptables` **BUT NO SOLUTION**

_CAN YOU SHOW WHAT RULES ARE NEEDED_

Answer (score 2):

Those two servers `ns1.imsingh.com` and `ns2.imsingh.com` do indeed not have a `A` record.
As far as I can see those servers aren't owned by GoDaddy anyway.

Contact GoDaddy and figure out which servers you need to use.

Comment: that i know, but please tell me what to do how to add A record.

those are my private name server. i also own imsingh.com.

A record for imsingh.com is 59.177.154.251, and same is for ns1, ns2

thanking you

Comment: Then the problem is in the `imsingh.com` zone. That zone doesn't respond correctly, queries to it fail with `SERVFAIL`.

Comment: Don't try to run your own nameservers - calling your domain donotrape.me won't stop them from being violated in all sorts of ways until you've learnt a lot more about DNS.

Answer (score 0):

dig on imsingh.com shows :

```
imsingh.com.        172683  IN  NS  ns1.imsingh.com.
imsingh.com.        172683  IN  NS  ns2.imsingh.com.
```

But ns1 and ns2 does not respond on port 53. You should probably check your fw conf to open DNS traffic to your ns1 and ns2.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your firewall somtehing like:

```
# Redirect DNS traffic (tcp/53 and udp/53) to DNS server
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 \
                              -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:53

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 53 \
                              -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:53

iptables        -A FORWARD    -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 \
                              -o eth1 -d 192.168.1.2    \
                              -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables        -A FORWARD    -i eth0 -p udp --dport 53 \
                              -o eth1 -d 192.168.1.2    \
                              -j ACCEPT
```